# Windows 10 dont applies static IP settings of WiFi profile at reconnect

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ip, network-adapter, device-manager

Windows 10. When i enter static IP information (addr, GW, DNS) for a specific WLAN network, the connection works fine. After disconnect, the reconnect tooks slightly longer than usual, and the connect dialog prints "Kein Internet, Gesichert" (No internet connection). There is actually no Internet connection. The IP information is not applied to the interface, refer to "ipconfig in cmd".

[image: ipconfig in cmd]

Surprisingly, the properties dialog prints the IP settings, which it to have be, refer to "WIFI network settings".

[image: WIFI network settings]

After pressing the Edit- and then the Save-button (with leaving the displayed properties unchanged), windows gets instantly its connection back. With Ipconfig i see, that the IP settings were correctly applied.

Even if i leave the WIFI network, connect to a new one (which works), leave that network, and connecting to the old one with static IP infos, it still not work.

The following things i already tried, but w/o success

- Reboot
- I've deleted the corresponding WIFI profile and recreated it
- I've tried to reset the TCP/IP stack with the command `netsh int ip reset`

Further investigations

- Connecting to another AP (Android hotspot), previously added static infos wont applied, too
- Not the same behavior on another windows machine. On the other Windows machine, the Interface got directly the IP infos and was connected to the internet.
- With another WiFi Adapter on the problem-machine, it worked well, too. Seems, there is a problem with the Network Adapter...

I've expected that windows applies these settings automatically. Am i going right, that windows should save the ip details, and automatically apply these on reconnect? The new dialog suggests to me that it should be. It seems, that the settings were saved per WIFI profile.

Is there a way to completely reset (quasi factory reset) all the WiFi things?

Edit: Moved solution into an answer.

Comment: You should [edit] your question, remove the solution, and submit an answer containing a fully documented solution written in English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helped to uninstall the network adapter via `devmgmt.msc` and then search for changed hardware. The name of the adapter to be uninstalled can be found in the overview of the network adapters `ncpa.cpl`.

Unfortunately, this operation will cause the loss of the WLAN profiles that were stored with the respective adapter.